# How to phrase a hierarchical read rule in Firestore correctly

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This should be fairly easy but I'm running into a problem with reads in hierarchical data in Firestore.  Taking the example in the official documentation and adapting it a little, I have...

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if resource.data.visible == true;

        // Explicitly define rules for the 'landmarks' subcollection
        match /landmarks/{landmark} {
          allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cities/$(city)/landmarks/$(landmark)).data.promoted == true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to be the way to express a read rule at lower levels where the condition is based on a value for a field in the nested data, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore could only follow that rule *at best* for a `get` of a single document, not a `list` of a collection.  "Security Rules are not Filters" is the mantra, here: Security rules will NOT just pass through documents that meet the rules while blocking those that don't; *if* a request *could* result in a blocked file, the ENTIRE REQUEST will be rejected.  Since the only document that *could* be allowed would be a single.get() of a document

the use of get() in Security Rules must specify a *single document*, even if the query is for a collection.  As such, about the only way a similar rule could work would be:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if resource.data.visible == true;

        // Explicitly define rules for the 'landmarks' subcollection
        match /landmarks/{landmark} {
          allow read: if resource.data.promoted == true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

this could be accessed with either a .get() of a single documentRef that *happens* to have `promoted` set, *or*
`collectionRef..where(field:'promoted', opStr:'==', value:'true')`
such that the query condition matches Security Rule condition - i.e. the *query* filters the documents such that they *all* match the security rule.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this with quite a few variations.  I'm using Swift but the query syntax is `ref.collection(cities).document("Paris").collection(landmarks).document("Eiffel Tower").whereField("promoted", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments() {...`.  There's no problem when the lower rule is `allow read: if true`.  Troubleshooting this is tough.  Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: .where() clauses only apply to LIST operations(i.e. on a collection) - so normally we would be looking at ```ref.collection(cities).document("Paris").collection(landmarks).whereField("promoted", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments() {...```
The .where() qualifies the sub-set of documents to be returned.  They aren't "lower level". In your example it would return all "landmark" documents that are marked "promoted".  Are you trying to get all *cities* that have promoted landmarks?

Comment: Yes, I understand what a `where` is doing in the query. The query’s purpose here is to find all promoted landmarks in one city, Paris’ in the example. The query then matches the `if` statement in the security rule.

Comment: AGAIN - Security Rules are *not* filters - they will NOT select some documents and not others,  Either ALL the records in the query are allowed,  or NONE.  Your QUERY is the filter; the Security Rule is your protection.

Comment: The "lower rule" will NOT act as a filter.

Comment: I don’t know how to see this other than a sort of Venn diagram. The query is only requesting (I.e. filtering) a list of documents that have promoted set to true for one city. The rule is a matching Venn. I’ve tried adding a field in the landmark document which shows the city but even then a rule and query that are perfectly aligned (allow read if resource.data.city == $(city)`) matched with `ref..document(“Eiffel Tower”).whereField(“City”, is equal to: “Paris”)..` does not work. There should be no document which does not satisfy the rule while still satisfying the query.

Comment: What you "see' is not particularly relevant to how Firestore works.  It really doesn't depend on *your* vision, but on Firestore's code.  I have explained in painstaking detail above exactly how to accomplish what you want.  Read the documentation, follow the examples.

Rules are NOT matching "Venn" diagrams.  Rules are NOT to help you select documents, they are to prevent unauthorized access.  They are not at all the same thing.

The documentation is there for your help.  Please read it.

Comment: Is it still not working for you? Your query seems to be off, I understand that you should use 'where' clause on a collection and not on a document.